# Reload UITableView Header View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, header

I have a headerView in my UITableView which a bunch of stats in, I set it like this in the viewDidLoad method:

`self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self headerView];`

The `headerView` method, just returning my view. However, the stats only update when the is loaded, if I go to a child view from this one and return the stats don't update, so how can I reload this view when returning to it from a child view controller? Instead of just when the view loads?

Let me simplify this:

How can I reload the `tableHeaderView` upon returning to the view from a child view controller? So I press back to return to my view with the header and I need to reload it at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346944/changing-uitableviews-section-header-footer-title-without-reloading-the-whole-t

Comment: Did you try calling `[tableView reloadData]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header view is not automatically reloaded when you reload the `UITableView`. You have to manage this view yourself. If you want to update it before your view controller appears:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    MyHeaderView *v = (MyHeaderView *)[[self tableView] tableHeaderView];
    [v updateWithData:[self someData]];
}
```